# Does ActionBarSherlock 4.2 support search suggestions for a SearchView?

Tags: java, android, android-searchmanager

A month ago, I dropped-in ActionBarSherlock 4.2 into my project. I got everything to work, except the search suggestions for my `SearchView`. The way I was creating search suggestions was using [the method in the Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-custom-suggestions.html).

Does ActionBarSherlock support search suggestions? I tried to dig through [the issue](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/659) list on the Github page but the issue seems closed but I can't seem to follow the discussion and understand whether it really is a resolved or not. I thought that some of you who've been using ActionBarSherlock might know better.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It doesn't. But I have found a way to make it query your ContentProvider.
I looked into the source of SuggestionsAdapter from API 17 where the query executes and got an idea of replacing this method. Also I found that ActionbarSherlock's SuggestionsAdapter does not use your SearchableInfo.

Edit com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SuggestionsAdapter in your ActionBarSherlock project:

Add a line

```
private SearchableInfo searchable;
```

in constructor, add

```
this.searchable = mSearchable;
```

Replace getSuggestions method with this one:

```
public Cursor getSuggestions(String query, int limit) {

    if (searchable == null) {
        return null;
    }

    String authority = searchable.getSuggestAuthority();
    if (authority == null) {
        return null;
    }

    Uri.Builder uriBuilder = new Uri.Builder()
            .scheme(ContentResolver.SCHEME_CONTENT)
            .authority(authority)
            .query("")  // TODO: Remove, workaround for a bug in Uri.writeToParcel()
            .fragment("");  // TODO: Remove, workaround for a bug in Uri.writeToParcel()

    // if content path provided, insert it now
    final String contentPath = searchable.getSuggestPath();
    if (contentPath != null) {
        uriBuilder.appendEncodedPath(contentPath);
    }

    // append standard suggestion query path
    uriBuilder.appendPath(SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_QUERY);

    // get the query selection, may be null
    String selection = searchable.getSuggestSelection();
    // inject query, either as selection args or inline
    String[] selArgs = null;
    if (selection != null) {    // use selection if provided
        selArgs = new String[] { query };
    } else {                    // no selection, use REST pattern
        uriBuilder.appendPath(query);
    }

    if (limit > 0) {
        uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter("limit", String.valueOf(limit));
    }

    Uri uri = uriBuilder.build();

    // finally, make the query
    return mContext.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, selection, selArgs, null);
}
```

Now it queries my ContentProvider but crashes with default adapter saying that no layout_height loading some xml file from support library. So you have to use custom SuggestionsAdapter. This is what worked for me:

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView;

import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.app.SearchableInfo;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public final class DrugsSearchAdapter extends CursorAdapter
{
    private static final int QUERY_LIMIT = 50;

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private SearchView searchView;
    private SearchableInfo searchable;

    public DrugsSearchAdapter(Context context, SearchableInfo info, SearchView searchView)
    {
        super(context, null, CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);
        this.searchable = info;
        this.searchView = searchView;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View v, Context context, Cursor c)
    {
        String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1));
        TextView namet = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_drug_name);
        namet.setText(name);

        String man = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_2));
        TextView manuf = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_drug_manufacturer);
        manuf.setText(man);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context arg0, Cursor arg1, ViewGroup arg2)
    {
        return this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_drug_search, null);
    }

    /**
     * Use the search suggestions provider to obtain a live cursor.  This will be called
     * in a worker thread, so it's OK if the query is slow (e.g. round trip for suggestions).
     * The results will be processed in the UI thread and changeCursor() will be called.
     */
    @Override
    public Cursor runQueryOnBackgroundThread(CharSequence constraint) {
        String query = (constraint == null) ? "" : constraint.toString();
        /**
         * for in app search we show the progress spinner until the cursor is returned with
         * the results.
         */
        Cursor cursor = null;
        if (searchView.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE
                || searchView.getWindowVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
            return null;
        }
        try {
            cursor = getSuggestions(searchable, query, QUERY_LIMIT);
            // trigger fill window so the spinner stays up until the results are copied over and
            // closer to being ready
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.getCount();
                return cursor;
            }
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        }
        // If cursor is null or an exception was thrown, stop the spinner and return null.
        // changeCursor doesn't get called if cursor is null
        return null;
    }

    public Cursor getSuggestions(SearchableInfo searchable, String query, int limit) {

        if (searchable == null) {
            return null;
        }

        String authority = searchable.getSuggestAuthority();
        if (authority == null) {
            return null;
        }

        Uri.Builder uriBuilder = new Uri.Builder()
                .scheme(ContentResolver.SCHEME_CONTENT)
                .authority(authority)
                .query("") 
                .fragment(""); 

        // if content path provided, insert it now
        final String contentPath = searchable.getSuggestPath();
        if (contentPath != null) {
            uriBuilder.appendEncodedPath(contentPath);
        }

        // append standard suggestion query path
        uriBuilder.appendPath(SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_QUERY);

        // get the query selection, may be null
        String selection = searchable.getSuggestSelection();
        // inject query, either as selection args or inline
        String[] selArgs = null;
        if (selection != null) {    // use selection if provided
            selArgs = new String[] { query };
        } else {                    // no selection, use REST pattern
            uriBuilder.appendPath(query);
        }

        if (limit > 0) {
            uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter("limit", String.valueOf(limit));
        }

        Uri uri = uriBuilder.build();

        // finally, make the query
        return mContext.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, selection, selArgs, null);
    }

}
```

And set this adapter in SearchView

```
searchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(new DrugsSearchAdapter(this, searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()), searchView));
```

Comment: Many thanks for taking the time to write this great answer :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm the one that opened [the github issue](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/659) for this. It is working on the dev branch. The current version (4.2) doesn't have the fix. It was completely fixed by this [commit](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/commit/e5f1661210b8d526386f61f01677a6360ddd6e63), but I would suggest just checking out the dev branch and trying it.

Comment: as the dev-branch currently seems to be merged into master and ahead of it, the fix-commit is in master, too and using master should work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I'm wrong here or I changed something on accident, but the above answer does not work and the ActionBarSherlock SuggestionsAdapter does not work. All I get are null pointers in runQueryOnBackgroundThread. It never goes into bindView etc. either, yet it manages to display suggestion results. I think android.app.SearchManager is somehow overriding ABS with getSuggestions() but I'm not sure. I'm still trying things out...