# ActionBarSherlock SearchView - how to programmatically show drop down

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I use SearchView from ActionBarSherlock library. I would like to show drop down list with recent search queries when my searchView is empty. (Something like on youtube application). Now it displays drop down when I insert text with at least two letters. 
Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already an article about that

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-recent-query-suggestions.html
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/searchable-config.html

If you encounter troubles with ActionBarSherlock refer to this question
[Does ActionBarSherlock 4.2 support search suggestions for a SearchView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13798668/does-actionbarsherlock-4-2-support-search-suggestions-for-a-searchview/14260518#14260518)

Comment: There is difference between SearchView from standard android library and SearchView from ABS. On older devices i can't use SearchableIfo. So, I use setSuggestionsAdapter but elements from this adapter are showing only when i insert at least two letters. In standard SearchView, suggestions diplay when we insert first letter.

Comment: Set android:searchSuggestThreshold="1" in your searchable.xml in you want to query after one letter.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/searchable-config.html

Comment: I've done something similar: found autocompleteTextView by mSearchView.findViewById(R.id.abs__search_src_text);
and set setThreshold(0); on it. Thanks.